# ODBC Driver - Invalid string or buffer length

Tags: jboss5.x, java-6, jdbc-odbc

I upgraded my JDK from 1.5.0 to 1.6.0 and then i got this when i try to connect MS SQL through ODBC driver:

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid string or buffer length.
```

Any ideas on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Paste your database connection string

Comment: Provider=mondrian;Jdbc=jdbc:odbc:DSN;JdbcUser=sa;JdbcPassword=password12*;JdbcDrivers=sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver;Catalog=jndi:/localhost/DwMondrianWeb/WEB-INF/queries/Loans-AssetQuality.xml;